QGIS - divide inside of polygon into smaller defined polygons
I have the following polygon in QGIS. It is roughly 260m x 20m

Within it, I would like to create smaller polygons like so in QGIS:
12  - 20ft rectangles
15  - 40ft rectangles
^ for 7 rows
(very badly drawn) example below

Can anyone recommend the best way to go about this? I don't fancy having to try and draw them all by hand, so I'm praying there's a different workflow

Do you only have that one polygon? If more than one do all have the same rotation

@BERA just that one polygon which I want to fill with 20ft and 40ft rectangles
